# EJB Timer Service Active/In-Active

Tags: scheduled-tasks, ejb-3.0, glassfish-3

For back-end job processing i m using Ejb3 Scheduler(Timer Service). That Schedulers are packed in a EAR file. I am deploying this EAR to 2 glassfish server with a apache for load balancing. The problem is 2 glassfish started their Schedulers, it means the same scheduler start 2 times. i need to divide the job between 2 server means for example i am having 6 scheduler then 3 scheduler start by server1 and others will server2 with same copy of EAR.

Can you suggest how to prompt to start scheduler if one server started already?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are having cluster like environment. Singleton will not help in this case, as there is one bean instance for each JVM.

You can use a temporary database table as a common reference point to store the scheduled jobs details. The respective schedular will pick a job/row from it & might update/delete the execution result status/row accordingly.

Therefore, all the schedulars will pick from common location, they won't be doing redundant things. Else, you can configure Quartz probably for such scenario, into your application as alternative.